# C# Regex : let's parse Objective-C

Tags: c#, .net, ios, objective-c, regex

I'm trying to parse an x-code project to translate it.

I've got 3 or 4 big applications to translate so i start a C# project to do this.

I'm having big troubles with Regex.

Does anyone know how to extract string like this:

String to parse :

```
title = [[Object alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Title" andParam:@"A complex \"param\"" andAFormat:@"Hello %@",toto];
```

Result should be like an array of :

`ObjC
"My Title", 
"A complex \"param\"", 
"Hello %@"`

I'm pretty lost with this...

Thank you.

Comment: Word to the wise... Regular Expressions are the wrong way to build conversion/parse libraries for full languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to translate a set of strings within a project, then I'd strongly recommend converting all string instances such as @"My Title" to the localizable macro:

NSLocalizedString(@"My Title", @"Comment which will appear above My Title, such as ObjC \"My Title\"");

These can then be extracted using the genstrings command line utility, which will generate a strings file with entries like:

/* Comment which will appear above My Title, such as ObjC "My Title" */
@"My Title" = @"My Title";

This means that integrating the translated strings back into your project becomes very simple.

The native way to approach localizing strings within your application is documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html